# why my chrome extension manifest is not allowing jquery?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Here is my manifest:

```
{
  "name": "test.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
  ],
   "content_scripts": [
  {      
  "js": ["jquery.js"]
  }
 ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Set this page's color.",
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
     "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and my popup.js

```
function click(e) {
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,
  {code:"$('img').css('display','none');
  window.close();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
...
  }
});
```

But for some reason
i get the error

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem in your code

- There are not match Patterns in your manifest, so jQuery did not run\injected in any places, so `$` or `jQuery` keywords are undefined.

## Solution

Modify your manifest to include URL where jQuery is to be injected(Do not forget to declare permission(s) for the URL's.

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/*"]
      "js": ["jquery.js", "myscript.js"]
    }
  ],
```

The above injects jQuery in a Google Page, use `<all_urls>` to inject in all websites.

## References

- [Content Scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html)
- [Match Patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html)